# Swift UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError with CAAnimation

Tags: swift, background, swiftui

I am asynchronously running a CAAnimation (animated gradient) in my app as the background image. When the home button is clicked (going to the home screen w/o closing the app) and then you re-enter the app, there is a UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError. I would really appreciate if someone could figure this out. A side effect of this error is the animation stops playing/it pauses. Thanks! (look below for more info)

I used a symbolic break to see the error and the result is the image below:
[image: Error Result]

The code for the background is here (used in a SwiftUI View) as GradientView():

```
struct GradientView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

typealias UIViewControllerType = GradientBackground


func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GradientView>) -> GradientView.UIViewControllerType {
    return GradientBackground()
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GradientView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GradientView>) {

}
}

class GradientBackground : UIViewController {

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientSet = [[CGColor]]()
var currentGradient = 0
let gradOne = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4620226622, green: 0.8382837176, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
let gradTwo = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8323456645, blue: 0.4732058644, alpha: 1).cgColor
let gradThree = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1).cgColor



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    animatedGradient()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gradientSet.append([gradOne, gradTwo])
    gradientSet.append([gradTwo, gradThree])
    gradientSet.append([gradThree, gradOne])

    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true

    //gradient.colors = [gradOne, gradTwo]

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
}

func animatedGradient() {
    var prevGrad: Int!

    if currentGradient < gradientSet.count - 1 {
        currentGradient += 1
        prevGrad = currentGradient-1
    }
    else {
        currentGradient = 0
        prevGrad = gradientSet.count-1
    }

    let gradChangeAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    gradChangeAnim.duration = 1.5
    gradChangeAnim.fromValue = gradientSet[prevGrad]
    gradChangeAnim.toValue = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradient.setValue(currentGradient, forKeyPath: "colorChange")
    gradChangeAnim.delegate = self
    gradient.add(gradChangeAnim, forKey: nil)
}
}
extension GradientBackground: CAAnimationDelegate {
func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
    //if anim.
}
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

    if flag {
        if let colorChange = gradient.value(forKey: "colorChange") as? Int {
            var number = colorChange + 1
            if number == gradientSet.count {
                number = 0
            }

            gradient.colors = gradientSet[number]

            animatedGradient()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but logged error looks like Apple's issue. As for restoring animation on application reactivate you can try the following code below I used in test, that works.

```
import Combine

...

class GradientBackground : UIViewController {

...
private var subscribers = [AnyCancellable]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    animatedGradient()

    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification)
        .sink { _ in
            self.gradient.removeAllAnimations()
        }.store(in: &subscribers)
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)
        .sink { _ in
            self.animatedGradient()
        }.store(in: &subscribers)
}
```